# Call Object based off of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to call an object from my node backend through react, but I am trying to do so based off of a string.  So if the string is 'Cat', I am wanting to access the `Cat` object and any other key/values under it.

Example of what the code looks like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let catName = 'Cat' //this string is actually passed in
    this.callApi()
      .then(res => this.setState({ catsName: res.catName.name }))
                                 //catsName: res.Cat.name works
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  callApi = async () => {
    //lets say this example route has all animals in the world as objects
    const response = await fetch('/animals');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

    return body;
  };
```

I know that it isn't working because it's a string, but trying to convert both the string or the object hasn't been working either.  I'm limited in my node knowledge, any advice or clues?  Or is this not even possible and I'm calling it wrong?  Thanks ahead of time.

Example of what the node backend looks like for this example if helps.  All animals would have key values in their api files (name, age, herbivore, etc..):

```
app.get('/animals', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ Cat, Dog, Cougar, Wolf, etc.... });
});
```

Comment: Thank you all VERY much for your help, my appreciation cannot be expressed enough.  That was amazingly quick.  I should have come here much sooner, but now I can name the dent on my forehead and wall I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the brackets syntax when you want to access a dynamic keys within an object.

```
catsName: res[catName].name
```

Check this documentation of **[Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)**

Comment: I was even searching all over that site, thank you for the link!

Comment: Shubham sorry for the delay, will do, still a stack newb :)

Answer (score 1):

You need array notation for that.

```
res[catName].name
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `res.catName.name` to `res[catName].name`